# Need help designing a proper sql query

Tags: sql, join, self

I have this table:

```
DebitDate | DebitTypeID | DebitPrice | DebitQuantity
----------------------------------------------------
40577       1             50           3
40577       1             100          1
40577       2             75           2
40578       1             50           2
40578       2             150          2
```

I would like to get with a single query (if that's possible), these details:
date, debit_id, total_sum_of_same_debit, how_many_debits_per_day

so from the example above i would get:

```
40577, 1, (50*3)+(100*1), 2 (because 40577 has 1 and 2 so total of 2 debits per this day)
40577, 2, (75*2), 2 (because 40577 has 1 and 2 so total of 2 debits per this day)
40578, 1, (50*2), 2 (because 40578 has 1 and 2 so total of 2 debits per this day)
40578, 2, (150*2), 2 (because 40578 has 1 and 2 so total of 2 debits per this day)
```

So i have this sql query:

```
SELECT      DebitDate, DebitTypeID, SUM(DebitPrice*DebitQuantity) AS TotalSum
FROM        DebitsList
GROUP BY    DebitDate, DebitTypeID, DebitPrice, DebitQuantity
```

And now i'm having trouble and i'm not sure where to put the count for the last info i need.

Comment: According to what you want the records must be group by? -- I mean you need to group the records with Debitdate or DebitTypeID. You cannot put both of them.

Answer (score 1):

You would need a correlated subquery to get this new column.  You also need to **drop** DebitPrice and DebitQuantity from the GROUP BY clause for it to work.

```
SELECT   DebitDate,
         DebitTypeID,
         SUM(DebitPrice*DebitQuantity) AS TotalSum,
         (   select Count(distinct E.DebitTypeID)
             from DebitsList E
             where E.DebitDate=D.DebitDate) as CountDebits
FROM     DebitsList D
GROUP BY DebitDate, DebitTypeID
```

Comment: I've already tried that, but for the first 40577 line it gives me 2, and for the second 40577 line it gives me 1.

Comment: @Shay - I get what you are saying, see the new subquery

Comment: Brilliant! this is exactly what i was looking for, i didn't know how to select a field that comes from a subquery (like you did), thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help you.

```
SELECT      DebitDate,  SUM(DebitPrice*DebitQuantity) AS TotalSum, Count(DebitDate) as DebitDateCount
FROM        DebitsList where DebitTypeID = 1
GROUP BY    DebitDate
```